# Saving matplotlib animation as movie; movie too short

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an animation that I made with matplotlib that I'm saving using `matplotlib.animation.Animation.save()`. This works well, but my movie ends before my animation ends.

I've tried changing frame rate, interval, and movie format from `.mp4` to `.avi`. Is there a frame or movie size limit? How could this be fixed?

Here is my code:

```
# Updates animation.
def update_line(num, data, line):
    line.set_data(data[..., :num])
    return line,


fig1 = plt.figure()
l, = plt.plot([], [], '-')
line_ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig1, update_line, fargs=(np.array(trajectory), l), interval=25, blit=True)

line_ani.save(file_title + '.avi')
plt.show()
```

While the movie should be about 15 seconds long, it ends up being 3 seconds long. I also use `plt.show()`, and the animation is much longer on the matplotlib display window.

In case it matters, I'm running on Ubuntu, with matplotlib 3.03 and python 3.6.

Comment: As you have it, the animation goes infinitely long. In such case, you wouldn't want an infinitely long movie file, right? So you need to set the number of `frames` (some `num_max` in your case).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest you're right. I was able to solve it literally 30 seconds before your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I was able to fix this by making the parameter `frames=len(trajectory[1])`.

In short, if you can predict the length of your movie in frames, use `repeat=False` and `frames=number_of_frames` as parameters to `.save()`.

Leaving this answer up for others to fix their bugs.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who found this and OP's answer did not work, here's the solution that worked for me:

When creating the FuncAnimation object, add the named parameter `save_count`, which tells the animator how many frames to save when `save()` is called.

Here's the one from my code:

`self.ani = anim.FuncAnimation(self.fig, lambda i: self.animate(i), frames=self.update_time, repeat=False, init_func=self.init_plot, interval=self._frame_len, save_count=self._max_frame)`

A bonus is that this also lets you keep your `frames` argument as a function (i.e. for interactivity when you call `plt.show()` instead of `save()`).

Source: https://holypython.com/how-to-save-matplotlib-animations-the-ultimate-guide/